# Add xmlns to SoapParam in PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap-client

I have the proper SOAP request being created except that I need the LogOn node to have an xmlns attribute. This is what the attribute looks like: xmlns="http://www.ultipro.com/dataservices/bidata/2". I have used SOAPUI to test the request and it appears that if I add that xmlns then the response should be a success.

Here is my current code:

```
function Login($username, $password, $clientaccesskey, $useraccesskey)
{
    class LogOn
    {
        function __construct($request)
        {
            $this->logOnRequest = $request;
        }
    }
    // Class handler for the request
    class logOnRequest {
        function __construct($usr, $pwd, $cak, $uak)
        {
            $this->UserName = $usr;
            $this->Password = $pwd;
            $this->ClientAccessKey = $cak;
            $this->UserAccessKey = $uak;
        }
    }

    // Conversion to a SOAP object
    $lor = new LogOnRequest($username, $password, $clientaccesskey, $useraccesskey);
    $lo = new LogOn($lor);

    $logOnRequest = new SoapVar($lor, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'logOnRequest');
    $loi = new SoapVar($lo, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing', 'Action', 'http://www.ultipro.com/dataservices/bidata/2/IBIDataService/LogOn');
    $headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing', 'To', 'https://service4.ultipro.com/services/BiDataService');

    try 
    {
        $soapclient = new SoapClient('https://service4.ultipro.com/services/BiDataService', array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 'encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'exceptions' => TRUE, 'trace' => TRUE));
        $soapclient->__setSoapHeaders($headers);

        // Direct call to the LogOn method and SOAP parameter pass
        $response = $soapclient->LogOn(new SoapParam($loi, 'LogOn'));

        echo json_encode($response);

        echo htmlentities($soapclient->__getLastRequest());
    }
    catch(SoapFault $fault){
        echo $fault->faultstring;
    }

}
```

This is what my request looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://www.ultipro.com/dataservices/bidata/2" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <env:Header>
      <ns2:Action>http://www.ultipro.com/dataservices/bidata/2/IBIDataService/LogOn</ns2:Action>
      <ns2:To>https://service4.ultipro.com/services/BiDataService</ns2:To>
   </env:Header>
   <env:Body>
      <ns1:LogOn>
         <logOnRequest>
            <UserName></UserName>
            <Password></Password>
            <ClientAccessKey></ClientAccessKey>
            <UserAccessKey></UserAccessKey>
         </logOnRequest>
      </ns1:LogOn>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

It needs to look like this:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://www.ultipro.com/dataservices/bidata/2" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <env:Header>
      <ns2:Action>http://www.ultipro.com/dataservices/bidata/2/IBIDataService/LogOn</ns2:Action>
      <ns2:To>https://service4.ultipro.com/services/BiDataService</ns2:To>
   </env:Header>
   <env:Body>
      <ns1:LogOn xmlns="http://www.ultipro.com/dataservices/bidata/2">
         <logOnRequest>
            <UserName></UserName>
            <Password></Password>
            <ClientAccessKey></ClientAccessKey>
            <UserAccessKey></UserAccessKey>
         </logOnRequest>
      </ns1:LogOn>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```